# json-server returns 404 for specific URI

Tags: json, http, json-server

I use json-server and my codes are like below.

db.json

```
{
  "en-boards": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "News",
      "uri": "/board/en-news"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Politics",
      "uri": "/board/en-politics"
    }
  ],
  "board-en-news-threads-latest": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "poster": null,
      "zero-post": "This is a thread 0.",
      "attachment-path": null,
      "post-number": 100,
      "utc-timestamp": "2022-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "poster": null,
      "zero-post": "This is a thread 1.",
      "attachment-path": null,
      "post-number": 100,
      "utc-timestamp": "2022-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

routes.json

```
{
  "/api/*": "/$1",
  "/api/en-boards": "en-boards",
  "/api/board/en-news/threads/latest": "board-en-news-threads-latest"
}
```

I run `json-server --watch db.json --routes routes.json --middlewares middleware.js --port 4000`

When I run `curl -i http://localhost:4000/api/en-boards`, I get `200 OK`, but when I run `curl -i http://localhost:4000/en-news/threads/latest`, I get `404 Not Found`. `wget` and React app behave in the same way.

### Environment

- MacOS 13.0
- Node.js 18.11.0
- json-server 0.17.0
- curl 7.84.0
- wget 1.21.3
- React 18.2.0

Thank you for read. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have faced something similar before...
In my case, I needed something like base URLs (1) and endpoint paths (2) like the below -
[image]

```
{
"/api/board/*": "/$1",
"/api/*": "/$1",
"/en-boards": "/en-boards",
"/en-news/threads/latest": "/board-en-news-threads-latest"}
```

This would cater to the following endpoints being hit

```
http://localhost:3000/api/board/en-news/threads/latest
http://localhost:3000/api/en-news/threads/latest
http://localhost:3000/en-news/threads/latest

http://localhost:3000/api/board/en-boards
http://localhost:3000/api/en-boards
http://localhost:3000/en-boards
```

**Note**: for */api/board/en-news/threads/latest* to route to */board-en-news-threads-latest*, the order for the base URLs needs to be maintained (i.e.)

```
"/api/board/*": "/$1",
"/api/*": "/$1",
```

Hope this helps :)